# Script Notify for ms-appdata

Tags: c#, javascript, html, windows-8.1

I want to notify my web view from button in html file and trigger the javascript:

```
function notify(str) {
    window.external.notify(str);
}
```

The event captured using `wv_ScriptNotify(..., ...)`:

```
void wv_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    Color c=Colors.Red;
    if (e.CallingUri.Scheme =="ms-appx-web" || e.CallingUri.Scheme == "ms-appdata")
    {
        if (e.Value.ToLower() == "blue") c = Colors.Blue;
        else if (e.Value.ToLower() == "green") c = Colors.Green;
    }
    appendLog(string.Format("Response from script at '{0}': '{1}'", e.CallingUri, e.Value), c);
}
```

I set the html file on `ms-appx-web` and it running well, and I realize that the html file must be store into local folder. So I change the `ms-appx-web:///.../index.html` to `ms-appdata:///local/.../index.html`.

Already search in microsoft forum and get [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7a5caded-3d6f-4ff2-91c3-746dd03ca8eb/webview-scriptnotify-from-msappdata). On that thread there is a solution using resolver, but I'm still confusing, how can it notify from javascript like using `window.external.notify`? And what kind of event in C# side that will capture the "notify" from javascript other than "ScriptNotify"?

---

### Update

There is a solution from [here](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/07/17/what-s-new-in-webview-in-windows-8-1.aspx), example using the resolver and it said to use `ms-local-stream://` rather than using `ms-appdata://local` so I can still use the `ScriptNotify` event. But unfortunately the example using the `ms-appx` that means using the `InstalledLocation` not the `LocalFolder`.

Trying to googling and search in [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-US?query=ms-local-stream) site for the documentation for `ms-local-stream` but the only documentation is just the format of `ms-local-stream` without any example like this `ms-local-stream://appname_KEY/folder/file`.

Based from that documentation, I made some sample to try it:

```
public sealed class StreamUriWinRTResolver : IUriToStreamResolver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The entry point for resolving a Uri to a stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IAsyncOperation<IInputStream> UriToStreamAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri == null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        string path = uri.AbsolutePath;
        // Because of the signature of this method, it can't use await, so we 
        // call into a separate helper method that can use the C# await pattern.
        return getContent(path).AsAsyncOperation();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper that maps the path to package content and resolves the Uri
    /// Uses the C# await pattern to coordinate async operations
    /// </summary>
    private async Task<IInputStream> getContent(string path)
    {
        // We use a package folder as the source, but the same principle should apply
        // when supplying content from other locations
        try
        {
            // My package name is "WebViewResolver"
            // The KEY is "MyTag"
            string scheme = "ms-local-stream:///WebViewResolver_MyTag/local/MyFolderOnLocal" + path; // Invalid path
            // string scheme = "ms-local-stream:///WebViewResolver_MyTag/MyFolderOnLocal" + path; // Invalid path

            Uri localUri = new Uri(scheme);
            StorageFile f = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(localUri);
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await f.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            return stream.GetInputStreamAt(0);
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw new Exception("Invalid path"); }
    }
}
```

And inside my MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // The 'Host' part of the URI for the ms-local-stream protocol needs to be a combination of the package name
    // and an application-defined key, which identifies the specific resolver, in this case 'MyTag'.

    Uri url = wv.BuildLocalStreamUri("MyTag", "index.html");
    StreamUriWinRTResolver myResolver = new StreamUriWinRTResolver();

    // Pass the resolver object to the navigate call.
    wv.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(url, myResolver);
}
```

It always get the exception when it reach the `StorageFile f = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(localUri);` line.

If anybody ever got this problem and already solved it, please advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After debugging it, I found something interesting, the `BuildLocalStreamUri` part is already make the `ms-local-stream` automatically.

I made some changes on the `getContent` method inside `StreamUriWinRTResolver` class:

```
public sealed class StreamUriWinRTResolver : IUriToStreamResolver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The entry point for resolving a Uri to a stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IAsyncOperation<IInputStream> UriToStreamAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri == null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        string path = uri.AbsolutePath;
        // Because of the signature of this method, it can't use await, so we 
        // call into a separate helper method that can use the C# await pattern.
        return getContent(path).AsAsyncOperation();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper that maps the path to package content and resolves the Uri
    /// Uses the C# await pattern to coordinate async operations
    /// </summary>
    private async Task<IInputStream> getContent(string path)
    {
        // We use a package folder as the source, but the same principle should apply
        // when supplying content from other locations
        try
        {
            // Don't use "ms-appdata:///" on the scheme string, because inside the path
            // will contain "/local/MyFolderOnLocal/index.html"
            string scheme = "ms-appdata://" + path;

            Uri localUri = new Uri(scheme);
            StorageFile f = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(localUri);
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await f.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            return stream.GetInputStreamAt(0);
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw new Exception("Invalid path"); }
    }
}
```

Change the file path on the MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // The 'Host' part of the URI for the ms-local-stream protocol needs to be a combination of the package name
    // and an application-defined key, which identifies the specific resolver, in this case 'MyTag'.

    Uri url = wv.BuildLocalStreamUri("MyTag", "/local/MyFolderOnLocal/index.html");
    StreamUriWinRTResolver myResolver = new StreamUriWinRTResolver();

    // Pass the resolver object to the navigate call.
    wv.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(url, myResolver);
    wv.ScriptNotify += wv_ScriptNotify;
}

protected override void wv_ScriptNotify(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CallingUri.Scheme == "ms-local-stream")
    {
        // Do your work here...
    }
}
```