# Is there a workaround for Script Notify not working on UWP ms-appdata

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am developing an application for `Xamarin.UWP` which is trying to inject Javascript into a local html file **(uri: ms-appdata:///local/index.html)** like so:

```
async void OnWebViewNavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsSuccess)
    {
        // Inject JS script
        if (Control != null && Element != null)
        {
            foreach (var f in Element.RegisteredFunctions.Where(ff => !ff.IsInjected))
            {
                await Control.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { string.Format(JavaScriptFunctionTemplate, f.Name) });
                f.Injected();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then when the Javascript method is called this will call the `OnWebViewScriptNotify` method so that I can proccess the request in my application.

The trouble is this doesnt work for some [kind of security reasons](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7a5caded-3d6f-4ff2-91c3-746dd03ca8eb/webview-scriptnotify-from-msappdata?forum=w81prevwCsharp):

> This was a policy decision we made that we have had feedback on so we
>   re-evaluate it. The same restriction doesn't apply if you use
>   NavigateToStreamUri together with a resolver object. Internally that's
>   what happens with ms-appdata:/// anyway.

I then tried what is advised in this case which was to use a resolver as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18979635/2987066

But this has a massive affect on performance, because it is constantly converting all files to a stream to load in, as well as certain pages loading incorrectly.

I then looked at using the `AddWebAllowedObject` method like so:

```
private void Control_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    if (Control != null && Element != null)
    {
        foreach (var f in Element.RegisteredFunctions)
        {
            var communicator = new HtmlCommunicator(f);
            Control.AddWebAllowedObject("HtmlCommunicator", communicator);
        }
    }
}
```

Where `HtmlCommunicator` is:

```
[AllowForWeb]
public sealed class HtmlCommunicator
{
    public JSFunctionInjection Function { get; set; }

    public HtmlCommunicator(JSFunctionInjection function)
    {
        Function = function;
    }

    public void Fred()
    {
        var d = 2;
        //Do something with Function
    }
}
```

and in my html it is like so:

```
try { window.HtmlCommunicator.Fred(); } catch (err) { }
```

But this doesn't work either.

So is there a way to work around this rediculous limitation?

Comment: From [http://blog.damiendelaire.com/2016/06/communicating-back-and-forth-with.html](http://blog.damiendelaire.com/2016/06/communicating-back-and-forth-with.html) I read that `For some weird reason you need to add create this in new WRC library and mark this class this  [AllowForWeb]` I will investigate more

Comment: I noticed in the link above and [this link](https://www.suchan.cz/2016/01/hacking-uwp-webview-part-2-bypassing-window-external-notify-whitelist/) they both use `ms-app-web`, So I'm not sure whether the last method works for `ms-app-data`. putting the class in another WRC library didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found this answer: [C# class attributes not accessible in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32066351/2987066)

It says:

> I believe you need to define the method name starting with a lower
>   case character.
>
> For example: change GetIPAddress to getIPAddress.
>
> I tested it on my side and found if I use the upper case name
>   'GetIPAddress', it won't work. But if I use getIPAddress, it works.

So I tried this:

I created a new project of type `Windows Runtime Component` as suggested [here](http://blog.damiendelaire.com/2016/06/communicating-back-and-forth-with.html) and I changed my method names to lower case so I had:

```
[AllowForWeb]
public sealed class HtmlCommunicator
{
    public HtmlCommunicator()
    {
    }

    public void fred()
    {
        var d = 2;
        //Do something with Function
    }
}
```

In my javascript I then had:

```
try { window.HtmlCommunicator.fred(); } catch (err) { }
```

and in my main UWP project I referenced the new `Windows Runtime Component` library and had the following:

```
public HtmlCommunicator communicator { get; set; }

private void Control_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    if (Control != null && Element != null)
    {
        communicator = new HtmlCommunicator();
        Control.AddWebAllowedObject("HtmlCommunicator", communicator);
    }
}
```

And this worked!

Comment: can you give a small function thats return model from HtmlCommunicator class irrespective of void.